# Ordering of Parent Child Relation in Big Query on a specific conditions

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, parent-child, tree-traversal

We want to print the root parent child combination with two condition in bigquery.

Condition:-

1. If "Y" is there in the row of SUCCESSOR parent then the PREDECESSOR node will become the parent.
2. All the child nodes will be printed in ascending then all the parent nodes should be printed in the ascending order and all the parent of parent in ascending order.

Table Column:-

```
Child | Parent | Type
```

Input Data:-

```
Child | Parent | Type 
YA011 | YA010 | 
YA012 | YA010 |
YA022 | YA020 |
YA030 | YA020 |
YA021 | YA022 |
YA190 | YA000 | Y
YA200 | YA190 | Y
YA010 | YA200 | Y
YA020 | YA200 | Y
```

To Implement the 1st condition we had applied below query and temp2 table we had created and the 1st condition has been successfully implemented.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP2 AS (WITH RECURSIVE generation AS (
  SELECT child, parent, [parent] parents FROM sample_table
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.child, t.parent, parents || [t.parent]
    FROM generation g
    JOIN sample_table t ON g.parent = t.child AND IFNULL(t.type, 'N') <> 'Y'
)
SELECT child, ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] parent
  FROM generation
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(parents) DESC) = 1)
```

Now for 2nd condition we had tried with below query but we are not getting the result as expected:-

```
WITH RECURSIVE generation AS (
  SELECT child, parent, [parent] parents, 0 as level FROM temp2
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.child, t.parent, parents || [t.parent] , level +1 as level
    FROM generation g
    JOIN temp2 t ON g.parent = t.child AND level <=9
), temp as (
SELECT child, ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] parent, level
  FROM generation
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(parents) DESC) = 1 ) 
select * from temp
Order by level, child
```

Output from the above query :-

```
Row     Child | Parent | level
1.         YA011 | YA010 | 0
2.         YA012 | YA010 | 0
3.         YA021 | YA020 | 0
4.         YA022 | YA020 | 0
5.         YA030 | YA020 | 0
6.         YA010 | YA200 | 1
7.         YA020 | YA200 | 1
8.         YA200 | YA190 | 2
9.         YA190 | YA000 | 3
```

If you see in the above output the row 6 should be after row 2 as YA010 is the parent of YA011 and YA012.

For now in our query all child are listed 1st then there parents then there parents of parents.

Excepted o/p :-

```
Child | Parent | 
YA011 | YA010 |              1st child of YA010
YA012 | YA010 |              2nd child of YA010
YA010 | YA200 |.             Then YA010
YA021 | YA020 |              1st child of YA020
YA022 | YA020 |              2nd child of YA020
YA030 | YA020 |              3rd child of YA020
YA020 | YA200 |              Then YA020
YA200 | YA190 |              Then parent of YA010 and YA020 i.e., YA200
YA190 | YA000 |              Then parent of YA200 i.e, YA190
```

Comment: There is a great solition for Hierarchy Queries in BigQuery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71192741/hierarchy-queries-in-bigquery  You need to add an stop condition in the `on` clause. `on b.predecessor_job_id = a.successor_job_id  and a.type!="Y"`

Comment: Hi Samuel, yes I tried this solution also but the result is not as excepted, there can be a case where there are parent child relation without 'Y' also. The condition is that if 'Y' is there stop the traversal. But it is not necessary the column type will have "Y" always.

Comment: Would you be more specific for your second condition, *in last we want to print the parent node.* ?

Comment: @Jaytiger I had updated the output with more details

Comment: @A.K.S updated example is slightly different than the previous one,  and still 2nd condtion is not clear to me. anyway kindly check below query having result as your expected output

Comment: @Jaytiger I had added the one more o/p with the comments to elaborate the 2nd condition

Answer (score 1):

Consider below query.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE generation AS (
  SELECT child, parent, [parent] parents FROM sample_table
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.child, t.parent, parents || [t.parent]
    FROM generation g
    JOIN sample_table t ON g.parent = t.child AND IFNULL(t.type, 'N') <> 'Y'
),
output AS (
  SELECT child, ARRAY_REVERSE(parents)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] parent
    FROM generation
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY child ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(parents) DESC) = 1
),
-- for 2nd condition
orderings AS (
  SELECT *, [child] path FROM output WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM output)
   UNION ALL
  SELECT g.*, path || [g.child] FROM orderings o JOIN output g ON o.child = g.parent
)
SELECT child, parent FROM orderings ORDER BY FORMAT('%t', path);
```

**Query results**

[image]

Note: I've referenced below link for DFS(Depth-First Search)

- [https://docs.teradata.com/r/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/WTxMQ~RIQURp9UKzLxGDDA](https://docs.teradata.com/r/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/WTxMQ%7ERIQURp9UKzLxGDDA)

Comment: Thanks. the 1 condition is met but the 2 condition is still not matched. I had updated the question with one more example and comments.

Comment: @A.K.S, I've updated the query for 2 condtion. kindly check that out.